# Swift. Could not build Objective-C module

Tags: objective-c, module, swift

I have such a problem. I take project from svn repository and it doesn't work on my computer but works on another one. Compiler said that he couldn't build Objective-C module View (int project is View.h file, it's out main view file) and also compiler said that he can't find View-Swift.h, but i can't understand what it is and where it must be created and for what?

Comment: May be somebody forgot to commit missed files to SVN? Check machine that compiles well, does it have missed files?

Comment: It just was a cycling in modules(first module had reference on second , second on third and third on first)

Comment: Happy that you've found the problem.

Comment: @VasylKhmil Can you answer your own question and accept the answer (since you've found the solution)? This question will then appear as answered. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just was a cycling in modules(first module had reference on second , second on third and third on first)